# How can I add a scope just for some actions on ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a classic posts-belongs-to-user association. I want to apply a default_scope to all the actions like `#index` so it lists my posts only. But I want the ability to see posts from anybody when I go to the `#show` action if follow a link to it.

How can I avoid the default_scope to be applied on that action?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

ActiveAdmin.register CertificationModel do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      current_user.posts
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: By the way, you can use the built-in [`scope_to`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/60d8be97ec2c29a871f55bd28e00ca9ec9257028/docs/2-resource-customization.md#scoping-the-queries) method to accomplish the same thing you're currently doing with `scoped_collection`

Answer (score 7):

You can call super for other action on which you don't want your `scoped_collection` to be called.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      if ['index', 'action2', 'action3'].include?(params[:action])
        current_user.posts
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution was simple: to keep `scoped_collection` and to redefine `#show` action.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
    end

    def scoped_collection
      current_user.posts
    end
  end
end
```